# Bounty question did not receive attention, should I not get my bounty back?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I offered a bounty of 100 on a question [related to chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805754/native-message-exe-not-getting-invoked-since-chrome-update). It hardly got any attention and is going to expire in 3 hours. Not much page views and not even a single answer or comment. All the comments to the question were posted before I offered the bounty. Should I not get my bounty back?

Comment: The bounty help page clearly states bounties are not refundable. You bought *advertisement*; your question was advertised as promised. If no one bit, then either your question is too esoteric for most, or at least didn't *sound* appetising.

Comment: Whatever the page states, I think that in cases like this bounty should be refunded.  Discuss!  Do we want bounties to be offered?  Because after an experience like this I am quite sure I would never offer another bounty again.

Comment: bounty is the wrong word then.  bounty == reward. you don't payout rewards for nothing accomplished.

Comment: @JohnBowers  Right -  no-answers-at-all questions should have the **bounty refunded**.  However, it's a certainty that SO / management / keenUsers will ever change anything: it's a totally moribund social structure.  It will never be changed.  "point-hounds" really control the site.  For example, the most obvious thing in the world would be a "reward!" button.  But point-hounds panic because that could lead to "cheating", you know.    All IMO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. There is no guarantee that a bounty will have any net effect, beside page views. If the technology isn't used very wide, or people don't like the question, they are free to skip the question.

As stated very clearly in the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), bounties are **non-refundable**, for any reason.

But no worry, I am sure this meta post will get you some attention.

Comment: Yes I knew that bounties are non-refundable and the logic is fine with me. But I just want to say that IF the question don't even get much "page views", then there should be some clause where some amount is refunded.

Comment: Then you are just unlucky. Your question was either too hard, or unpopular for some reason. Note that there are just 70 questions on [tag:chrome-native-messaging].

Comment: Yes I think the same Patrick because the question is regarding chrome-extension which is well known and not getting an answer was unexpected.

Comment: Also see the vote count in the 'top user list': http://stackoverflow.com/tags/chrome-native-messaging/topusers.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I am at peace now that why the question did not get much attention. :)

Comment: Bounties are like buying radio advertising. You've no guarantee that anyone is actually listening, but they're not going to broadcast your ad without paying. ["Half the money I spend on advertising is wasted; the trouble is I don't know which half."](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/1992.html)