# Who will take the bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I have a question about the bounty. I wasn't able to locate my situation in already provided questions/answers.

There is a question (not mine) where I posted an answer which has been accepted with score 2. I started a bounty on that question, no one answered the question better than me, and I got an additional +2 to my accepted answer.
Where will the bounty go after expiration and will it?

Comment: If after the starting of the bounty there were posted new aswers with more than 2 votes, the best voted answer will get 50% of the bounty. Otherwise the bounty is _lost_. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: thanks for the response, but no new answers have been posted

Comment: This is simple: The bounty is _gone_ :)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272979/319875

Comment: so already posted questions can't get the bounty?

Comment: why downvote without comments?

Comment: Reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty, only new answers get the bounty automatically. You can offer the bounty to existing answers.

Comment: Meta is tough. If you didn't search well or didn't read the faq you get downvotes. Also you get downvotes if people don't like what you proposed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get your own bounty under any circumstances. So if it's auto-awarded, half will go to the highest-voted answer with at least +2 score posted during the bounty period, if any meet those criteria; otherwise it goes into `/dev/null`. If you award it manually, it will go to whichever answer you pick (including those posted before or after the bounty period, but not including one of your own).

Comment: so it's gone :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: what if the question already had some answers, even accepted one? Don't they deserve some piece of pie?

Comment: @minitoto: Not really. They weren't posted because of the bounty, so they don't get a chance at the automatic award, which is really only there in case the bountier forgets to come back and award it manually.

Comment: why than i can select the reason for the bounty "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty"?

Comment: @minitoto: ... because that's the only way to hack that particular reward setup into the system? If you want to reward a particular answer, *reward that answer*. Don't expect the system to magically know which existing answer is super-special.

Comment: ok, fair enough, thanks for the answer